# As TDs não usam toda a largura da tabela

Tags: css, table

Eu criei uma página HTML com uma tabela para armazenar quatro colunas (nome, data, código e botão de remover) e, abaixo, um formulário.

Eu quero que a tabela possua uma largura e altura fixa de `95vw` e `80vh`. Para fazer isso, estou utilizando o `display: block`. O problema é que, ao colocar isso, as linhas da tabela deixam de usar toda a largura disponível.

Vejam o código abaixo:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 95vw;
}
tr {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="users_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Data de Expiração</th>
        <th>Código</th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alberto Freitas Pereira</td>
        <td>5-10-2020</td>
        <td>s2d4fDSA3fzzxxDSDQER12e</td>
    <td>Remover</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    
<form>
    <input type="text" value="something">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

O que eu devo fazer para manter a largura e altura fixa com as linhas preenchendo a tabela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplesmente aplique o `width` e o `height` na própria tabela, sem usar o  `display: block` nela:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 95vw;
}
tr {
  text-align: center;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="users_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Data de Expiração</th>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Remover</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alberto Freitas Pereira</td>
    <td>5-10-2020</td>
    <td>s2d4fDSA3fzzxxDSDQER12e</td>
    <td>Remover</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    
<form>
  <input type="text" value="something">
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Evidentemente, o problema é que, ao fazer isso, as linhas da tabela assumirão altura máxima para preencher os `80vh` de altura que colocamos para `table`. Expanda o *snippet* para ocupar a tela cheia para enxergar o problema com mais clareza.

Portanto, acho que aplicar altura específica *na tabela* pode não ser tão necessário nesse caso. Você pode criar um elemento "pai" em relação à tabela para criar uma borda e dar a impressão de tabela "vazia no final":

```css
#users_table_wrapper {
  width: 95vw;
  height: 80vh;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
tr {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
tr > *:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
td {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="users_table_wrapper">
  <table id="users_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Data de Expiração</th>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Remover</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alberto Freitas Pereira</td>
      <td>5-10-2020</td>
      <td>s2d4fDSA3fzzxxDSDQER12e</td>
      <td>Remover</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
    
<form>
  <input type="text" value="something">
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Ou, como alternativa, simplesmente não definir uma altura específica na tabela, mas sim uma altura máxima (`max-height`), assim:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  max-height: 80vh;
  width: 95vw;
}
tr {
  text-align: center;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="users_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Data de Expiração</th>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Remover</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alberto Freitas Pereira</td>
    <td>5-10-2020</td>
    <td>s2d4fDSA3fzzxxDSDQER12e</td>
    <td>Remover</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    
<form>
  <input type="text" value="something">
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```